# Determine which bindings caused computed property to update

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a controller with a computed dependency tree like

```
a
  b
    c
      d
  e
    c
  f
    c
```

- updating `a` should re-compute all properties
- the bindings for `c` are `b`, `e`, `f`

How can I log out which binding caused a computed property to update? I want to do something like

```
const ctrl = Ember.Controller.extend({
  a: null,
  b: Ember.computed('a', foo),
  c: Ember.computed('b, e, f', function () {
    // did b, e, or f trigger this?
  }),
  d: Ember.computed('c', fizz),
  e: Ember.computed('a', buzz),
  f: Ember.computed('a', blah)
});

ctrl.set('a', 'foobar');
// => should see if b, e, or f was triggered last
```

Comment: Is it not possible to change the control flow such that you know who is setting which variable? It's best to avoid side effects completely in a computed property.  Through new functions like `this.updateC(value, changer)`, you could clear that up? These sorts of scenarios that you've asked about here often presented themselves in 2-way binding situations that were mitigated by emitting actions instead of changing values directly in components

Comment: @mistahenry the various computed properties i have in my controller are all "pure"; they don't `set` anything, just return a computation based on their bindings. thanks though.

Comment: Why must they know what changes or the order in which the items change?

Comment: @mistahenry the real issue i'm having is that some computed properties are not updating even their bindings are. that question has been asked to death but it's really hard to debug.

Comment: a computed property will only be evaluated if it's in a template or you explicitly call get. That means if a depends on b which depends on c, and c updates causing b to update, a will not update if `{{a}}` isn't in a template or if you aren't explicitly `this.get('a')` after this update

Comment: If you are experiencing a situation where the computed properties are not updating and they're in the DOM, open a new question with a `twiddle` or repo demonstrating the problem and I'd be happy to take a look at it